# Is it possible to retrieve the contents of a html textarea with XPath?

Tags: html, xpath, webdriver, browser-testing

I've looked all over but I can't find any leads. Is it possible to do something like:

```
//textarea/<some kind of function?>
```

or

```
<function>(//textarea)
```

I know I can do this using JS, or any number of other techniques, but I'm asking because I'm using WebDriver and Firefox to test a TinyMCE textarea input, and because of JS execution delays, I'd like to wait for the textarea to display a certain string after clicking a formatting control and the only way I can think of to achieve this in WebDriver is with `SlowLoadableComponent` and XPath. That or `Thread.sleep` but I'd like to avoid that ;)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you want to have webdriver click a TinyMCE button, wait, then look in the text area for a specific string?

Answer (score 0):

With TinyMCE, the editor area isn't actually a TextArea - it's an IFrame. Your best bet would be to use Google Chrome (or similar, with Developer-targeted features) to have a look at what TMCE generates. You can then use XPath with something like this:

```
//IFRAME
```

which will retrieve all IFRAMEs on the page - or you can add in properties:

```
//IFRAME[id="myiframe"]
```

which will retrieve all IFRAMEs on the page with the ID attribute set to 'myiframe'

Hope this helps :)